# 175 speak German ,150 French, 180 English, 160 Japanese. How many speak all of them?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Among 200 journalists, there are:

- 175 speak German
- 150 speak French
- 180 speak English
- 160 speak Japanese

Each journalist can speak at least one of the 4 languages.
What is the maximum possible number of journalists who can speak all of them?
What is the minimum possible number of journalists who can speak all of them?

---

**Attempt:**

For the maximum part, it should be $150$, because if there is more than 150, it means there are more than 150 who speak French which is not the fact.

From PIE

$$|G \cap F \cap E \cap J| = 465 - \left( |G \cap F| + |G \cap E| + | E \cap F| + |E \cap J| + |G \cap J| + |F \cap J| \right) + \left( |G \cap F \cap E| + |G \cap J \cap F| + |G \cap J \cap E| + |E \cap F \cap J| \right)  $$

so to find the minimum i have to find the maximum of the 
$$ \left( |G \cap F| + |G \cap E| + | E \cap F| + |E \cap J| + |G \cap J| + |F \cap J| \right) + \left( |G \cap F \cap E| + |G \cap J \cap F| + |G \cap J \cap E| + |E \cap F \cap J| \right)  $$

What is the idea?

Comment: Maximum is 150 because we assume that everyone that can speak English can speak the rest.

Comment: The last line is wrong.  It should have a minus sign for the sum of the triples.  Where did 465 come from?

Comment: @herbsteinberg $|G| + |E| + |F| + |J| - |G \cup E \cup F \cup J| = 465$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the minimum, you can observe that

- 25 don't speak German
- 50 don't speak French
- 20 don't speak English
- 40 don't speak Japanese

Thus $25 + 50 + 20 + 40 = 135$ is the maximum number of journalists who don't speak at least one language (in the case where the 4 previous sets are disjoint). Thus the minimum number who speak the four languages is $200 - 135 = 65$.

EDIT. In more details, let us partition the set $S$ of 200 journalists in 5 disjoint subsets, $S_1$ to $S_5$, with $|S_1| = 25$, $|S_2| = 50$,
$|S_3| = 20$, $|S_4| = 40$ and $|S_5| = 65$. Let now $E = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_4 \cup S_5$, $F = S_1 \cup S_3 \cup S_4 \cup S_5$, $G = S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_4 \cup S_5$ and $J = S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 \cup S_5$. Then 
$|E| = 180$, $|F| = 150$, $|G| = 175$, $|J| = 160$ and $|E \cap F \cap G \cap J| = |S_5| = 65$.

Comment: Is it possible for $|-G \cup -E \cup -F \cup -J | = |-G| + |-E| + |-F| + |-J| =165$, when total journalist must be 200?

Comment: If the union of your four sets is disjoint, yes.

Comment: (in your example) so $|-G|$ is $|E \cap J \cap F|$, $|-F| = |G \cap E \cap J|$, and so on?

Comment: No, the set of journalists is the disjoint union of five sets: $E^c$, $F^c$, $G^c$, $J^c$ and $S = E \cap F \cap G \cap J$. Thus $J^c = (E \cap F \cap G) - S$, etc.

Comment: I can't seem to be sure that it guarantees exist a distribution with $|E \cap F \cap G \cap J| = 65$, given the information in the question..

Comment: *exist a possible distribution ...

Comment: See my new EDIT.

Comment: Thanks. Would you consider this an advanced math-contest problem for Junior High students?